# Cog as slash command with optional mention

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I need to make this cog use slash commands, but I don't know how, please help me :sob:

```
import random
import asyncio
import discord
import json
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext import commands
import re
import os
import config


class Passport(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command(aliases=['p', 'ps'])
    async def passport(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
        with open("text/bdays.json", "r") as f:
            bdays = json.load(f)
        with open('text/sw.json', 'r') as f:
            sw_data = json.load(f)
        user = ctx.author if not member else member
        user_avatar_url = user.avatar.url if user.avatar else user.default_avatar.url
        embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Паспорт пользователя {user.display_name}", color=random.choice(config.colors))
        embed.set_author(name="NookLink",
                         icon_url=config.NookLinkImg)
        embed.add_field(name="Имя пользователя:", value=f'{user.name}#{user.discriminator}', inline=True)
        if str(user.id) in bdays:

            embed.add_field(name="Дата рождения:", value=bdays[str(user.id)], inline=True)
        else:
            embed.add_field(name="Дата Рождения", value="Не указано", inline=True)
        if str(user.id) in sw_data:

            embed.add_field(name="Код друга:", value=f'SW-{sw_data[str(user.id)]}', inline=True)
        else:
            embed.add_field(name="Код друга:", value="Не указано", inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Прилетел на остров Юки:", value=user.joined_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), inline=True)
        embed.add_field(name="Роли:", value=", ".join([role.mention for role in user.roles[1:]]), inline=True)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=user_avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)

        @commands.Cog.listener()
        async def on_ready(self):
            print('Cog "Passport" loaded')


async def setup(bot):
    await bot.add_cog(Passport(bot))
```

I just want this thing appear as slash command, and make it optional to ping people in command. Is it possible to just use standard `discord.app_commands`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `discord.app_commands` within a cog. An example is as follows:

```
@app_commands.command(name="passport")
@app_commands.guilds(discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID_HERE))
async def passport(self, ctx, member: discord.Member = None):
    await ctx.response.send_message("My cool slash command!")
```

Just make sure that you sync your commands, otherwise they won't appear. You could do something similar to the following.

```
@bot.event
async def setup_hook():
    await load_cogs() # random function to load all of your cogs...
    await client.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=GUILD_ID_HERE)) # syncs the stuff
    print("Loaded cogs and synced")
```

If you have any issues or questions just let me know. I tested it with this method and it worked perfectly, so if you can't get it to work just let me know. Have a great day/night!